# Merge conflict, when branches aren't modifying the same line

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I'm trying to wrap my head around git conflicts, why does merging these two result in a conflict?

file.txt on branch `master`:

```
This is line number one
```

file.txt on branch `feature`:

```
This is line number one
This is line number two
```

Comment: How does the file look in the common ancestor of `master` and `feature`? Merging works with respect to that common parent.

Comment: And the common ancestor would be ... the commit before I branched them out? The file wasn't there.

Answer (score 11):

Normally, this would not cause a conflict (assuming that there was not a second line in the base file). But in this case, you *added* file.txt separately to `master` and `feature` (which is why the file is not in the common ancestor). When a file is independently added to two branches that are then merged and they differ in any way, Git considers it a conflict.

The reason for this is that Git needs a base copy to determine what the state of the file should be after the merge. For example, let's say there *was* a base file, and it had only the one line. In that case, Git would know that a line was added in `feature`, and thus the final file would have the two lines. If the base file had two lines, however, Git would know that a line was removed in `master`, and thus the final file would have a single line. In your case, there is no base file, so Git does not know which version of the file should "win".